# Are there restriction which HiveQL can but SQL can't?

Tags: sql, hiveql

I plan to migrate to SQL from HiveQL, but I have no idea about the restriction or care point between the two language.
I know there are some restriction from SQL to HiveQL.

For example,
1:SQL can set the two or more table by one "FROM" statement, but the HiveQL can't.
2:SQL can sort by the column which isn't "SELECT", but the HiveQL can't.
3:SQL can use "IN" in "WHERE" statement, but the HiveQL can't.
And so on.

What I'd like to know is whether there are any restiction or care point when HiveQL get migrated to SQL.
I did some reserach, but I don't find any. Is there no restirction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

HiveQL is not a subset of SQL, no.

Among the differences noted at [alldifferences.net](https://alldifferences.net/differences-between-sql-and-hiveql/), HQL supports multi-table insert and `create table ... as select`, but SQL does not.

And see [this note on Hevo](https://hevodata.com/learn/hive-vs-sql/#language):

> Apache Hive uses a query language for its operations known as HiveQL. HiveQL is pretty similar to SQL and is highly scalable. SQL supports 5 key data types: Integral, Floating-Point, Binary Strings and Text, Fixed-Point, and Temporal. On the other hand, HiveQL supports 9 data types: Boolean, Floating-Point, Fixed-Point, Temporal, Integral, Text and Binary Strings, Map, Array, and Struct. SQL doesn’t support MapReduce but HiveQL does. The Views in SQL can be updated, unlike HiveQL.